# Zend-Framework -Forms and Translation

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-translate

Hi I have a form element error and it keeps breaking it when I wrap it in the translation function. I am using gettext for the translation.

I understand that if I have it set in the registry and Zend_Form it should pick it up automatically but how does poedit see it if at all?

My Bootstrap (Relevant Part):

```
    // Set the instance of Zend_Translate in the registry
    $registry->set('Zend_Translate', $translate);
    // Set an instance of Zend Translate object for validators
    Zend_Form::setDefaultTranslator($translate);
```

My Error Form:

```
public function formErrors(Zend_Form $form)
{       
        $registry = Zend_Registry::getInstance();
        $translate = $registry->get('Zend_Translate');
        $form->setTranslator($translate);

    if ($form->getMessages()) {
        $error = '<p class="errorBox">Error text here</p>';
        $error->setTranslator($translate);
        $error->getView()->translate($error);
        return $error;
    }
    return '';
}
```

Note:

```
 $this->translate('string to translate'); or $this->getView()->translate('string');
```

works everywhere else but not here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage within a form which I used on the last project was

```
$this->getTranslator()->translate('text to translate')
```

This was only used minorly as we had auto-detect resource paths so we did not need to call it. The way you want to use it does seem slightly different. I would recommend adding the extra call after getView() though as it could be the solution.